# Creating a concept for a non-template class with template methods

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts, member-functions

So, I'm trying to create a concept that checks, if a structure/class has the template method **void func(auto)** in it.

```
struct S
{
    void func(auto param)
    {
        // Do stuff ...
    }
};
```

Struct S doesn't have any template parameters, but it's member does. I pass my template parameter to the concept 'typename _Param', but it requires to specify this parameter, when I use my concept.

```
template <typename _T, typename _Param>
concept MyConcept = requires(_T&& obj, _Param&& param)
{
    {obj.func(param)};
};

// I don't want to specify 'int', it doesn't guarantee that S::func would be instantiated with this parameter. 
void workWithObject(MyConcept<int> auto&& obj);

int main()
{

    S s;
    workWithObject(s);

    return 0;

}
```

Is it possible to use MyConcept without specifying concrete type of method parameter?

Comment: "*if a structure/class has a template method in it*" Why do you care if the function is a template or not?

Comment: Don't use identifiers starting with underscore then an uppercase letter. These are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: without example what `workWithObject` does and why it needs this requirement it is hard to tell if your attempt to solve problem is correct. This is an example of question suffering from [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). I think this may have a seance only if you have template with template parameter, but `workWithObject` declaration do not indicate such case.

Comment: You can test whether `obj.func(expr)` is valid for any number of specific types of `expr`, but not, I think, for all possible types. If you use a private type, you could know that at least one template is involved, but that doesn't rule out a function constrained to allow all types except certain ones.

Comment: @MarekR, for instance, workWithObject can call obj::func with different parameters func(4), func("Some string"). Maybe obj is a logger. 
In my real code struct S is an allocator, and I have multiple types of them in codebase. I pass an allocator as a template parameter to another class. Now I want to constrain this parameter.

Comment: this list of types must be  implementation fixed or have to be passed to `workWithObject` a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think it works.

```
template <typename _T>
concept MyConcept = requires(_T&& obj, auto&& param)
{
    {obj.func(param)};
};

void workWithObject(MyConcept auto&& obj);
```

Comment: `auto` is not allowed in a `requires` expression parameter. MSVC incorrectly allows this.

Comment: it's unfortunate.